# Error selecting column recently inserted with ALTER TABLE in ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

1- Connect to a Oracle XE using Oracle.DataAccess

2- Execute a command to add a column to a table: alter table TABLE add COLUMN b int;

3- Execute a command to select this column

4- Read with a DataReader. Application raises IndexOutOfRangeException: Unable to find specified column in result set

5- Restart the application and the query runs correctly

Why DataReader can't access the column I have created just now?

Here is a large but simple code to test:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand())
            {
                com.Connection = con;

                // Create a test table
                com.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test (a int)";
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Add one column
                com.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Test ADD b int";
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Test";
                using (DbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dr.FieldCount.ToString());
                    // Here is showing "2", thats ok
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            using (OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand())
            {
                OracleTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    // Add a column to table already created
                    com.Connection = con;
                    com.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE Test ADD c int";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Insert a value, ok
                    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEST (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3)";
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }

                // Selecting only "c" column
                com.CommandText = "SELECT c FROM Test";
                using (DbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(dr["c"]).ToString());
                        // Showing correct value, ok
                }

                // Uncomment these lines to solve problem
                //con.Close();
                //OracleConnection.ClearAllPools();
                //con.Open();

                // Selecting all fields * from table
                com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Test";
                using (DbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dr.GetSchemaTable().Rows.Count.ToString() + " / " + dr.FieldCount.ToString());
                    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM: message are showing 2/2, but table haves 3 fields

                    if (dr.Read())
                        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(dr["c"]).ToString());
                    // Here throws IndexOutOfRangeException: Unable to find specified column in result set
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To me it sounds like some sort of metadata caching.  Maybe
the `OracleConnection.PurgeStatementCache()` method can help?

Comment: I tried PurgeStatementCache after adding the column and before selecting, but not worked.

Comment: `OracleTransaction` should be disposed and so should have it's own `using` block. You may choose to use [`OracleCommand.CreateCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleConnectionClass.htm#i1001011), as that will save you needing to assign the connection to the command yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the insert transaction is not committed yet when you execute the reader. I'm thinking you could verify this by closing the connection just after you insert and open it again just before you execute the reader (you may need to use OracleConnection.ClearAllPools)

Comment: In our real application we are using transactions and the behavior are exactly the same. Reopenning the connection don't resolve, but restarting application resolved.

Comment: Does that include calling OracleConnection.ClearAllPools? If you guys are using connection pooling the framework will keep the connection object in the pool even when you call "close"

Comment: ClearAllPools worked! I execute command to add the column, close conection, execute clearAllPools and reopen the connection. Worked fine and I dont need to restart all application. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, connection pooling is a beautiful thing but it can be a pain in the butt sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`OracleConnection.BeginTransaction`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleConnectionClass.htm#CHDJJDEF) to create a transaction and then [`Commit`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleTransactionClass.htm#i1015601) before selecting, like what is shown in the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleTransactionClass.htm#i1015601) in the documentation.

Comment: I tryed to start transaction before adding column, and commit after inserting values, but not worked too.

Comment: Could you please edit your example to show your use of transactions?

Comment: Thank you. It may not make any difference, but could you try using the `OracleTransaction` object returned by `BeginTransaction` and possibly updating the one in OracleCommand, e.g. `com.Transaction = con.BeginTransaction();`?